# Site to Site VPN not working after Fibre Upgrade

Tags: router, vpn

I have 3 VPNs connecting Sites A, B & C. Two of these (A & C) have just been upgraded to fibre (FTTP) and now only the A to B route is working.

All sites have Draytek routers.
Sites A & B are in UK, C is in France.

Site A now has an ONT connected to a FritzBox7530 which delivers VOIP and internet to a Draytek 2860 WAN2 now set to static ip. The Dial-Out VPN to Site C still functions. The ISP (Zen) insists their router must be first in line for the VoIP service to function. They will not offer any support or assistance for non-Zen hardware.

Site C has a direct fibre connection to a Livebox 5 (ie internal ONT). This delivers VoIP and internet to a Draytek 2830 as per "A". Routes A-C & B-C will not function in Dial-In or Dial-Out mode.

From this I assume that:

- **Yes**: The Fritzbox *will* pass a Dial-Out connection to "B".
- **Yes**: The Fritzbox *will* pass a Dial-In connection from "B".
- **No**: The Livebox *will not* pass a Dial-Out connection to "B".
- **No**: The Livebox *will not* pass a Dial-In connection from "B".
- **No**: The Livebox *will not* pass a Dial-Out connection to "A".
- **No**: The Livebox *will not* pass a Dial-In connection from "A".

So the problem seems to lie in the Livebox not passing the VPN in or out. I then changed the Livebox Firewall setting to "Low" and added NAT/PAT port forwarding for UDP ports 500 and 4500. This has not had any effect. Dial-In or Dial-Out will still not connect.

Port Forwarding on the Livebox is functioning. I can access the Draytek router from the internet, unless it is spoofing a loopback, I know some Zyxel units used to do this.

Doing away with the Livebox, unfortunately, is not a good solution. The internet and VoIP login  seems to be hard codeded and Orange will no doubt not release these without payment. The Livebox came with an enormous sweetener!

So I have run out of ideas, any help or suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: If the only change is on the FO you have to check if nothing else change, VLANs in the OLT or ONU, check if you si right dBs on between OLT  and ONU. Because if you didnt touch you VPN and the LAN configuration that mean the issue could be on the OLT  or ONU